# Storing subclasses in BDB in Java Using JPL

Tags: java, berkeley-db, berkeley-db-je

I am trying to persist, using JPL, My objects into a simple BDB. Problem is that If I try to store a subclass in the primary index I get an error (below).

The subclasses possess nothing at all different in terms of data but they are functionally different and I would like for the subclass to be the instance type marshalled. If I must, then the key can contain the class in question and I can instantiate it myself

Perhaps I need one index per subclass? But that doesn't seem right and certainly complicates the lookup process.

Example:

```
@Test
public void testStoreEntity() throws Exception {
    Random r = new Random();
    File directory = new File("C:\\Users\\chribong\\development\\code\\edifecs\\engineering\\platform\\icd-code-factory\\src\\test\\data\\" + r.nextInt(1000));
    directory.mkdirs();
    EnvironmentConfig envConfig = new EnvironmentConfig();
    envConfig.setAllowCreate(true);
    envConfig.setTransactional(true);
    Environment env = new Environment(directory, envConfig);

    StoreConfig storeConfig = new StoreConfig();
    storeConfig.setAllowCreate(true);
    storeConfig.setTransactional(true);
    EntityStore store = new EntityStore(env, "PersonStore", storeConfig);

    PrimaryIndex<Key,AbstractBdbIcdCode> index = store.getPrimaryIndex(Key.class,AbstractBdbIcdCode.class);

    index.put(new AbstractBdbIcdCode(10,"foo", ICDCode.Type.DIAGNOSIS,".*"));
    index.put(new BdbIcd10DiagnosisCode("A000")); // error here
    // java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class could not be loaded or is not persistent

}
```

classes

```
@Entity
public class AbstractBdbIcdCode implements ICDCode {

    @PrimaryKey
    private Key pk;

    protected String description;

    protected Set<String> concepts = new TreeSet<>();
    protected Set<String> antiConcepts = new TreeSet<>();
    protected Set<String> similarConcepts = new TreeSet<>();
}

@Persistent
public class Key {

    @KeyField(1)
    private ICDCode.Type type;

    @KeyField(2)
    private int version;
    @KeyField(3)
    private String code;

    public Key() {
    }
}

public class BdbIcd10DiagnosisCode extends AbstractBdbIcdCode implements ICD10DiagnosisCode{


    private transient String category;

    private transient  String etiology;

    private transient  String location;

    private String laterality;
    protected String extension;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out:

The subclass has to be

```
@Persistent
public class BdbIcd10DiagnosisCode extends AbstractBdbIcdCode implements ICD10DiagnosisCode{
}
```